# An inequality holding for odd primes

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, conjectures

Let $P_{\Sigma}(n)$ be the sum of all prime factors of $n$. Then there seems to be an inequality
$$p\ge P_{\Sigma}(rad(p^2-1))$$
for all odd primes $p$. Tested for the first million primes. Is this a known fact?

Comment: A slight simplifaction of the expression on the right side is to omit the rad since the prime factors of a number and its radical are the same.

Comment: @Peter - For me the prime sum of four is 2+2.

Comment: The inequality holds for $p\le 3\cdot 10^8$ and is in this range even strict with the exception $p=5$. Maybe it helps that one of $p-1$ and $p+1$ must be divisible by $6$ (for $p\ge 5$) so that the largest prime factors of $p-1$ and $p+1$ sum up to at most $\frac{2p+1}{3}$. In the case that one of $\frac{p-1}{2}$ and $\frac{p+1}{2}$ is prime, there is no counterexample upto $p=6\cdot 10^9$

Comment: I have no rigorous proof, but I find the observation not at all surprising. For primes of the form $6k\pm 1$, $p^2-1=36k^2\pm 12k=12k(k\pm 1)$. All of the factors of $2,3$ (at least three factors of $2$ and at least one and most frequently more than one factor of $3$ contribute only $5$ to the sum. If we assume that the sum of the other (non $2,3$) prime factors of any number $m$ is not larger significantly than $m$, the sum in total will not often be larger than $\approx 5+1.5k$, which is smaller than $\approx 6k$ for $k>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(n):= P_{\Sigma}(rad(n))$ to simplify the notation below. We want to show $P(p^2-1)\leq p$ for all odd primes $p$.

Notice that $\gcd(p-1,p+1)=2$ since $p$ is odd, and at least one of $p-1$ and $p+1$ will be divisible by $4$, hence we do not lose any primes by dividing both terms by $2$, and this also makes them coprime. So

$$P(p^2-1)=P((p-1)(p+1))=P\Bigl(\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{p+1}{2}\Bigr)=P\Bigl(\frac{p-1}{2}\Bigr)+P\Bigl(\frac{p+1}{2}\Bigr).(*)$$

The remaining factors are small, the following upper bound on $P(n)$ will help:

**Lemma.** $P(n)\leq n$ for all $n \geq 2$.

**Proof.** We can show a stronger statement $P_{\Sigma}(n) \leq n$, i.e. the inequality holds even when multiplicities are counted. Maybe there is more elementary method, but following strong induction works. First notice that $P_{\Sigma}(2)=2 \leq 2$. Then assume $P_{\Sigma}(k)\leq k$ for $k=2,3,\dots,n$ and we want to show $P_{\Sigma}(n+1)\leq n+1$. If $n+1=p^e$ is a prime power, this follows directly as $P_{\Sigma}(p^e)=pe\leq p^e$ (the last inequality can itself be shown by induction on $e$). If $n+1$ is not a prime power, we can write $n+1=ab$ where $a,b\geq 2$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$. But then $P_{\Sigma}(n+1)=P_{\Sigma}(ab)=P_{\Sigma}(a)+P_{\Sigma}(b)\leq a+b\leq ab=n+1$.
$\square$

Using the lemma on $(*)$ gives the desired claim
$$
P(p^2-1)\leq\frac{p-1}{2}+\frac{p+1}{2}=p.
$$
**Note:** We have not used that $p$ is a prime at all, so the claim holds for all $p\in \mathbb{N}$ odd.