# A useful way of characterizing primes?

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, prime-numbers, conjectures, big-picture

It's proved that if $P(n)$ is the sum of all different prime factors of $n$, then for all odd primes $p$ there is an inequality
$$p\ge P(p^2-1)$$

[An inequality holding for odd primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521411/an-inequality-holding-for-odd-primes/4522644#4522644)

Therefore there is an injection $j:\mathbb P \to \mathbb Q$, defined as
$j(p)=\frac{p}{P(p^2-1)}$. Now to me the following conjecture seems very natural:

> Given $\varepsilon >0$ there are two primes $p,q$ such that
> $|j(p)-j(q)|<\varepsilon$

The idea is to characterizing primes $p$ by the factorizations of their neighbors $p-1,p+1$.

---

**A metric on the prime numbers?**
$d(p,q)=|j(p)-j(q)|$ seems to fulfill the triangle inequality. Tested for all combinations of the 100 first primes.

I now realize that $d$ must be a metric because $j$ is an injection.

It is possible to define convergence of sequences of primes.

Comment: But $p\ge P(p^2-1)$ holds for (at least some) odd composites, too.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - the injection $j$ is restricted to primes.

Comment: I think Gerry's point is that *to characterize primes* usually means *to separate primes from non-primes*.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - Yes, I guess I mean characterizing relations between primes.